# Are equip cards destroyed when you attack the equipped monster twice

Tags: yu-gi-oh

In duel links equip cards like [Intrigue Shield](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Intrigue_Shield) and [Amazoness Heirloom](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Amazoness_Heirloom) are destroyed when the equipped monster is attacked twice.

I want to know does this happen in the real game of yugioh or just in the game?

Answer (score 2):

> In duel links equip cards like intrigue shield and amazoness heirloom are destroyed when the equipped monster is attacked twice i want to know does this happen in the real game of yugioh or just in the game

This you are experiencing is part of such equip card effects. Both of them happen to have the ability to save the monster they are equipped *once*, so when your monster has to be hit twice before it goes.

From the [Intrigue Shield](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Intrigue_Shield), emphasis mine:

> Target 1 face-up monster you control; equip this card to that target. **Once per turn**, while the equipped monster is in Attack Position, **it cannot be destroyed by battle**. You take no battle damage from attacks involving it.

And from [Amazoness Heirloom](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Amazoness_Heirloom):

> Equip only to an "Amazoness" monster. **Once per turn, that monster cannot be destroyed by battle**. When the equipped monster attacks, after damage calculation, destroy the attack target.

So this is part of the YuGiOh ruling in general, more specifically, due to the specific card texts and effects you mention.